# Como ordenar post de uma categoria por um Custom field?

Tags: wordpress, order

Tenho uma plataforma em `Wordpress` em que uma determinada categoria tem um Custom field (uma data).

É possível fazer com que ao mostrar os posts dessa categoria eles sejam ordenados pelo Custom field que adicionei?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa usar o meta_key como argumento:

```
$args = array(
    'order'         => 'desc',
    'meta_key'      => 'prod_preco',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type'     => 'produtos',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
...
```